# UIView strange behaviour with BOOL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I've made my custom `UIView` that I'm representing on `UIViewController`. View is presented on screen, but BOOL that I've setted on that instance of UIView to YES is not recognized.

Code:

UIView implementation:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self createInterface];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)createInterface
{
    if (self.isSplash == YES) {
       self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = DARK_BLUE;
        [self setupTimer];

    }
....
```

ViewController:

```
self.sponsorView = [[SponsorMechanismView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.logo.frame)+10, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100)];
    self.sponsorView.isSplash = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:self.sponsorView];
```

So, I set BOOL to YES, but in this UIView it is always NO.

Comment: When you set the `isSplash` to true, the `createInterface` method has already been executed.

Comment: Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Sure, overwrite the setter of `isSplash` and call `createInterface` there if `isSplash` has changed.

Comment: @FabioBerger please add this as answer, so I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fabio said, createInterface has already been executed.
What you can do is create your own init function. Something like this :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame isSplash(BOOL)isSplash
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    self.isSplash = isSplash;
    if (self) {
        [self createInterface];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And the call of the function will be like :

```
self.sponsorView = [[SponsorMechanismView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(self.logo.frame)+10, SCREEN_WIDTH, 100) isSplash:YES];
```

Comment: YES, YES, AND YES!!! Thanks! This has cleared me much stuff about UIView!

Comment: You are welcome :) Kindly accept the answer for future references.

Comment: you forgot to use `isSplash` parameter variable. In `if` statement you have to assign `self.isSplash = isSplash;` before `[self createInterface];`

Comment: @JayeshThanki : You are absolutely right. I modified my code few minutes before your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame AndIsFlash:(BOOL)isFlash{

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    [self createInterfaceAndisFlash:isFlash];
}
return self;
}

-(void)createInterfaceAndisFlash:(BOOL)isFlash
{
    if (isFlash == YES) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } 
}
```

Hope you Got an Idea.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments:

The `creatInterface` method has already been executed when you set `isSplash`.
You can solve this by overwriting the setter of `isSplash` and calling `createInterface` there.
Code example here:

```
- (void)setIsSplash:(BOOL)isSplash
{
    if (isSplash != _isSplash)
    {
        _isSplash = isSplash;
        [self createInterface];
    }
}
```